# Replace words in parras with random words from a list, on a timer / at random intervals

Tags: javascript, html

So this is a weird one. I'm trying to design a script where designated words or phrases are replaced from a list of options chosen at random. The script is supposed to run on a timer, so every few seconds, a replacement occurs.

That works just fine, but for some reason, my code causes random gaps to form between paragraphs. Even worse, it's not always a paragraph where some of the replacement happens. Here's my code. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

This is meant to be used in a lengthy article. You may need to add some Lorum Ipsum to see the error occur.

```js
var r1 = ["option1", "option2", "option3"];
var r2 = ["option1", "option2", "option3"];
var r3 = ["option1", "option2", "option3"];

var msecs = 3500;

setInterval(function() {
  var r1_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * r1.length);
  document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML = r1[r1_id];
  var r2_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * r2.length);
  document.getElementById('t2').innerHTML = r2[r2_id];
  var r3_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * r3.length);
  document.getElementById('t3').innerHTML = r3[r3_id];
}, msecs);
```

```css
.book {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  background-color: #FCF5E5;
  border: solid #966F33;
  border-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="book">
  <p>This is sentence one, <span id="t1">this should change</span>.</p>
  <p>This is sentence two, <span id="t2">this should change</span>.</p>
  <p>This is sentence three, <span id="t3">this should change</span>.</p>
</div>
```

Using Firefox 108.0.1

Comment: What do you mean? It works fine

Comment: I mean that when used in the longer article I am working on, the distance between any given two <p> tags will be increased, as if someone hit enter a bunch of times.

Comment: That’s called “text wrapping”. It’s supposed to break text lines so the text cannot flow out of its container. You can stop this in CSS by using `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: And if you want to see the text, you remove the `width` attribute from the container for all of the text, and it will resize the width automatically based on how long the text is.

Comment: @ParkingMaster This fixed it. Thanks! Can you type up a quick answer so I can close the question?

Comment: Sure. I don’t have time right now so I’ll do it tomorrow. Happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When text is too long and flows/overflows out of its parent container. Text will collapse so you can see all of it.

This is called “text wrapping”.

So this is the reason that it only happens with long text in your situation.

You can simply stop this in CSS by using a property called `white-space` and setting its value to `nowrap`.

Here’s an example with that:

###### CSS

```
.container {
  width: 100px; /* Very small for text */
}
p {
  white-space: nowrap; /* So remove text wrapping */
}
```

###### HTML

```
<div class=“container”>
  <p>This text is very long, it describes absolutely nothing.</p>
</div>
```

The only problem with this is that the text will go outside of the container, and it won’t look very nice.

If you want to resize the container to the length of the text, remove the `width` attribute from the container and it will resize based on the text length.